# Get usercontrol property value using Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control named lets say ucName that has a property named InitialValue.
 Everything's fine , Im rendering the control and setting the initial value.
 In my aspx page, Im doing like this:

```
<td>                
    <tagprefixName:ucName ID="Editor" runat="server"   InitialValue="bla bla"/>
</td>
```

I have a button that will post back the page, but before post backing, im doing:

```
<asp:Button  ID="SaveButton" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="SaveRes" OnClientClick="SaveValue()" />.
```

In javascript function I want to get the value of the initial value of my user control:
I tried many solutions, but they are either returning null or undefined.

```
function SaveValue() {
            var v= $("[id$=Editor]").attr("InitialValue");
            var v = $("#Editor").attr("InitialValue"); 
            var v= $("input[id$=Editor]").attr("InitialValue");
            var v= $("span[id$=Editor]").attr("InitialValue");//since the uc is rendered as span
}
```

How can I get the InitalValue of my uc ??
Thanks alot

**EDIT**
This is my html:

```
<span id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Editor"><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$2f1445d6-b13d-4f8f-9497-9c14e5d2b076" type="text" value="fgerf" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_2f1445d6-b13d-4f8f-9497-9c14e5d2b076" /></span>
```

NB: I tried using .val() .value() but still getting an empty

Comment: I assume jQuery is used. Added the tag

Comment: What does the html look like after rendering. Perhaps you do not HAVE id="Editor" but some "ctrl-000-Editor-have-been-mangled-by-MS"

Comment: yes sure, thats why im using ""span[id$=Editor]"", this sytaxe works fine with any asp control, but the problem is with the uc

Comment: I edited my question with the html code

Comment: it looks like its rendering an input inside a span

Comment: I think now all i have to do is to get the value of the input inside the span , right ?

Comment: Please show the HTML that is generated by the tag you are trying to access. If that includes a span, then yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The uc is rendered as an input inside a span has the uc's id, so the javascript code will be:

```
$("span[id$=Editor] input[type=text]").val();
```

Comment: In Question you didn't mention that the IntialValue is set as the text of textbox inside the UC.

Answer (score 0):

I'm presuming that the markup gets parsed on the server, and the resulting HTML code does not have this InitialValue property. Try viewing source to see what the actual code is and then paste it into the question.

If all the control does is set the contents of a span, then the following should work:

```
$("span#Editor").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** updated to use object names now that you've included the actual HTML in your page.  The only thing I'm still unsure of is whether `ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Editor` is the same every time or not.  If it's not the same every time, then you need to find a way (server-side) to assign an id that is constant so you have a reliable way to reference the object in the web page.

Adding this code will "save" the initial value to an attribute of the editor object when the page is first loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $editor = $("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Editor input");
    $editor.attr("data-initialValue", $editor.value());
});
```

And, then you can read back the initial value anytime later with this code:

```
$("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Editor input").attr("data-initialValue");
```

If, for any reason this code isn't working, then (in the ready handler), you need to find out whether it's not working because `$("ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_Editor input")` isn't being found or whether it's because it isn't able to save the data value on the object.

Comment: You will have to show us what the actual generated HTML looks like to know what JS to use to get the value.  We don't know what type of object `<tagprefixName:ucName ID="Editor" runat="server"   InitialValue="bla bla"/>` turns into in the actual page.

Comment: Hey. If you see the rendered HTML, you can clearly find that the attribute IntialValue is not assigned. So I suggest to assign this attribute to a span control inside the UC

Comment: Updated my answer based on the generated HTML you have now included.

Answer (score 0):

you could retrieve it in the aspx markup page using an expression like this

```
 var initialValue = <%= Editor.InitialValue %>;
```

Comment: Need to add that in single quotes. like below `var initialValue = '<%= Editor.InitialValue %>';`

Comment: thanks.  I didn't make any assumptions about a value of "blah blah"  I suppose we can assume its a string?